# Iframe won't load on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, http, iframe

All I'm trying to do is load an iframe on a click on the main image and then a click on the header of the iframe reloads the main image. However, this isn't working on Salesforce 1 becuause:

[blocked] The page at 'https://na16.salesforce.com/one/one.app' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.u2.com': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

A HTTPS version of the U2 site doesn't exist how do I solve this? Here is the code:

```
  <apex:page showHeader="False">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"><script>          

<apex:image value="{!$Resource.image1}" styleClass="image slide1"/>
<div id="news"></div>
<apex:iframe src="http://www.u2.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>

<div id="header" style="position:absolute !important;"></div> 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#theIframe').hide();
  $('.slide3').hide();

  $(".slide1").click(function(){
      $(".slide1").hide();
      $("#theIframe").show();
          $("#header").click(function(){
          $("#theIframe").hide();
          $(".slide1").show();
         });
  });


 });   

 </script>

 <style>    
 .image {
     width: 100%;


 }
 #header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     bottom: 91%;
     z-index: 1000;

 }
</style>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Salesforce .It is your chrome browser or mozilla blocking this .Modern day browsers have gone smart .

Check the below knowledge article link from Salesforce on this issue

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213361&language=en_US

Having said that browsers also provide mechanism to load unsafe script at your own risk ,

Here is your Visualforce page i opened in chrome

[image]

First time it blocked but then you will see on top of browser to load unsafe script

[image]

Using same in one/one.app I loaded your page on Salesforce 1 app also

[image]

Mozilla also blocks your content if it comes from unsecure site ,it also provides a small icon to unblock it .Please take a look at extreme right corner of your browser to load unsafe script

[image]

> All this are short term band aids while permanent solution is to get surgery with HTTPS implemented for your website .